# Do I need an international vehicle registration code in Norway when I have an EU license plate?

Tags: driving, automobiles, eu, norway

I will be driving in Norway. Do I need to equip my car with an international vehicle registration code sticker, if I have an EU license plate?

International vehicle registration code:

[image: International vehicle registration code for Czech Republic]

EU license plate for the Czech Republic:

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, you don't need an international vehicle registration code since the EU plate already has this affixed on it with the European Flag.

You should however have all of the cars documentations with you, such as; insurance, registration etc. just in case should you be pulled over by the respective authorities who may want to see paper work.

Comment: It is not required to bring or carry any proof of insurance to drive a car registered in another EEA country in Norway.

Comment: @Tor-EinarJarnbjo Are you sure? IMO you are required to **always** have proof of insurance with you even when you drive in the country where the vehicle is registered.

Comment: related question about the proof of insurance https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/35903/do-i-need-a-european-auto-insurance-green-card-while-driving-inside-the-eu

Comment: @DmitryGrigoryev Yes, I am sure. Third party liability insurance is mandatory in all EEA countries. Having license plates and a registration certificate is proof enough, that you also have the required insurance. AFAIK, carrying additional insurance certificates is not mandatory in any EEA country.

Comment: Nevertheless, it is always helpful to have the green insurance card with you.

Comment: @glglgl I doubt that a green card is very useful in Norway. Most Norwegians wouldn't even know what it is.

Comment: @Tor-EinarJarnbjo License plates at best only prove that you **had** insurance when you ordered them. Do you have to change your plates every year?

Comment: @Tor-EinarJarnbjo and if you come from the UK the registration plates don't even prove that you *had* insurance, because they're generally acquired with the car and never touched again.

Comment: @DmitryGrigoryev The common procedure if you don't extend your insurance is that your insurance company will inform the vehicle registration authorities, which will revoke your registration. If you don't voluntarily return or invalidate your license plates (exact procedures differ from country to country), it is not unlikely that the authorities will seek your vehicle to sack the license plates. At least the Norwegian authorities do so if you fail to pay insurance, vehicle tax or to present your car for mandatory technical certifications.

Comment: @Tor-EinarJarnbjo This is certainly not universal across EEA. Last time I got license plates for my car, the proof of insurance wasn't even on the list of documents I had to present.

Comment: @Tor-EinarJarnbjo Isn't Norway part of the green card insurance association?

Comment: In Germany, the plates have stickers on them which can be scratched if the authorities cancel the registration. In France, however, the plates remain valid. Instead, you get a "small" green card for proof of insurance. For the other countries, I don't know what procedures they ahve.

Comment: @DmitryGrigoryev You bring nothing in your comment, which contradicts what I am saying. I would assume that in most EEA countries, insurance companies and vehicle registration authorities exchange insurance documentation electronically without the car owner having to care.

Comment: @glglgl Norway is part of the green card insurance association. Why do you ask?

Comment: @Dmitry Grigoryev Not necessarily, it depends on local regulations. In some countries you don't need to have that proof always with you because the police will be able to look it up if they need it. (Yes, legally, not just in practice.)

Comment: @Tor-EinarJarnbjo I was (and am) confused because your statement "green card is not useful in Norway" and "Norway is part of green card association" don't seem to match. That's why I asked.

Comment: @DmitryGrigoryev No proof of insurance at all? Even no electronic insurance number?

Comment: @glglgl I have checked this, and it [appears](https://www.cartegrise-enligne.com/documents-carte-grise.php) that proof of insurance is required since August last year. Before that, you only needed to prove that the car is yours to register it.

Comment: @glglgl The green card is only needed if you travel to another non-EEA member state of the green card association. Starting in Norway, you must in most directions drive several thousand km to leave the EEA. Most Norwegians will never have taken their car outside the EEA, will never have needed a green card and therefore also not know that one exists. Norwegian insurance companies will only issue a green card if the holder explicitely requests one.

Comment: @Tor-EinarJarnbjo Thanks, wasn't aware of that.

Answer (score 6):

Norway and the Czech Republic have both ratified the Vienna Convention on Road Traffic. As you have the country sign (CZ) integrated in your plates, you don't need an extra sticker.

> CHAPTER IV. PROVISIONS APPLICABLE TO MOTOR VEHICLES AND TRAILERS IN
>   INTERNATIONAL TRAFFIC
>   Article 20
>   Every motor vehicle shall in
>   addition to the registration number display at the back, **inscribed on
>   a plate or on the vehicle itself**, the distinguishing sign of the place
>   of registration of this vehicle. This sign shall indicate either a
>   State or a territory which constitutes a distinct unit from the point
>   of view of registration. In the case of a motor vehicle drawing one or
>   more trailers this sign shall also be displayed at the back of the
>   single trailer or of the last trailer.

Comment: The Vienna Convention mandates an oval sticker (in Annex 3), but **within the EU** that requirement has been modified to the EU-standard number plate. An EU plate is not conformant outside the EU, and non-EU vehicles (or EU vehicles without an EU plate) require a Convention sticker within the EU.

Comment: @AndrewLeach so what does it mean? Norway is not part of EU.

Comment: Norway use the same format of plates as the EU but his own flag on the blue stripe instead of the EU-Flag. So there will be no problems for you.
 As I haven't seen any plates with an oval country sign, I assume that this applies only for the stickers.